# Using tor on FreeBSD

Tags: pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, obfs4, privoxy, freebsd

I followed this [method](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/40307/) on FreeBSD, however, I receive the following errors and I'm not sure why:

[image]

The only change made on default `tor` config file is to uncomment the following line on `/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
RunAsDaemon 1
```

The only change made on default `privoxy` config file was to add the following lines to `/usr/local/etc/privoxy/config`:

```
### Set the listen address to 127.0.0.1:8118
listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118
### forward privoxy to TOR
forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

Comment: Did you set 'SocksPort'  in your torrc?

Comment: @SuperSluether In torrc it is mentioned that `Tor opens a SOCKS proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't configure one below.` However, even when commenting out `SOCKSPort 9050 `, I get the same Privoxy 503 error.

Comment: I just set up Privoxy myself, and you seem to have incorrect syntax. To forward Privoxy to Tor, you need to use `forward-socks5t`, not `forward-socks4a`. http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#TOR

Comment: @SuperSluether Actually, after modifying usr/local/etc/privoxy/config statement to `forward-socks5t / 127.0.0.1:9050 .` and restarting both tor and privoxy services, I received the same `Privoxy 503` error.

Comment: @SuperSluether I feel like the ISP doesn't allow direct access to `tor` network. Therefore, looks like I need to use `bridges`/`obfs4`, I'm not sure how

Comment: That may be, but the error from Privoxy is because it can't find the local SOCKS proxy, which would still be running if Tor was blocked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46136/discussion-between-supersluether-and-user4838962).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, currently I'm using `tor` with chromium on freeBSD and it works fine. Just do the following steps:

Install `tor` on FreeBSD:

```
$ sudo pkg install tor
```

Install `obfs` proxy:

```
$ sudo pkg install obfsproxy
```

Add the following lines to `/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy managed
ServerTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy managed
```

Start `tor` on FreeBSD:

```
$ tor
Aug 17 10:31:14.954 [notice] Tor 0.3.0.10 (git-c33db290a9d8d0f9) running on FreeBSD with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1t-freebsd and Zlib 1.2.8.
Aug 17 10:31:14.954 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 17 10:31:14.955 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 17 10:31:14.975 [notice] Tor is not configured as a relay but you specified a ServerTransportPlugin line ("obfs2,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy managed"). The ServerTransportPlugin line will be ignored.
Aug 17 10:31:14.990 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 17 10:31:15.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 17 10:31:15.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 17 10:31:16.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Aug 17 10:31:17.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Aug 17 10:31:17.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Aug 17 10:31:18.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Aug 17 10:31:19.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Aug 17 10:31:20.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Aug 17 10:31:20.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Now, run chromium with tor proxy server:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/chrome --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0, EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"
```